# Mac OS equivalent of cp -s

Tags: macos, unix

In unix, the cp command has a -s option which allows:

```
 -s, --symbolic-link
          make symbolic links instead of copying

 -R, -r, --recursive
          copy directories recursively
```

Mac OS's version of cp doesn't support `-s` option. I want to issue the unix equivalent of `cp -Rs src destination`  in Mac OS. How would I do that?

Comment: The `-s` option isn't a *unix* option; there are plenty of Unix versions out there that don't support it including OS X.  It's not part of the POSIX standard, either.  Rather, it's an extension provided by the GNU Coreutils version of `cp`, as commonly found on Linux systems.  It's possible to install GNU Coreutils on OS X, for example, with third-party package managers like MacPorts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-s` flag present in GNU `cp` isn't part of the POSIX standard, and therefore isn't required on POSIX-compliant systems (like OS X). As such, there's no **direct** way to create symbolic links through the default `cp` on OS X.

You do, however, have a few options:

- Install GNU or FreeBSD `cp`, both of which have the `-s` flag. If you have homebrew installed, you can obtain GNU `cp` from the `coreutils` package.
- Roll your own solution. If all you want to do is recursively symlink the files in a directory. It just has to iterate over every file, making directories and symlinking normal files.